# Firebase Realtime DB inconsistent writes from Firebase functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I have a firebase functions which get triggered on onCreate for path `/activites/{uid}/{workId}`. This function then do some processing with the values and then updates the results (number value) to  `/users/{uid}/jobs`.

```
// value read from the snapshot function gives
// processing on value
// .
// .
// .
db.ref('/users/{uid}/jobs').transaction(currentVal => {
        return (currentVal || 0) + workIdValue;
})
```

My issue of inconsistent writes appears when let say function is **triggered 40 times in span of 1 second** per `uid` i.e. for the same path. This makes data inconsistent since each execution is having different currentValue from path `/users/{uid}/jobs`

I tired a solution of reading the value of the `jobs` from db to achieve consistency and then initiate transaction to update value but the result is still the same.

Other solution which I didn't tested is to use a lock mechanism by placing a boolean at the node `/users/{uid}/jobs/locked` and when trying to do update first check if boolean is false (meaning no other execution is modifying data) then set boolean true update the value and then release the lock setting value false.

Is there any better approach to solve this inconsistency?

Comment: try and use `onWrite()`

Comment: using on write will have no effect in my case since the inconsistency is not at the node where function is triggered but at the node where I'm writing the data in side function

Comment: Please edit the question show the entire function you've written.  It it shows now, it's hard to tell if you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @DougStevenson my problem is somewhat similar to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46257544/how-to-deal-with-firebase-trigger-function-execution-order , instead of http trigger I have a database trigger.

Comment: I'll try to update my code to include more code of the function