# Firebase Function update trigger - guarantee of accurate before/after data when updating using increment?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firestore Document `/users/aaa` with a value `unreadMessages` = 0.

I have a Firebase Function which triggers every time `/users/aaa` updates.

Say I perform the following increments (using https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#increment) in quick succession:

1. Update `/users/aaa`, increment `unreadMessages` (it's now 1)
2. Update `/users/aaa`, increment `unreadMessages` (it's now 2)
3. Update `/users/aaa`, increment `unreadMessages` (it's now 3)

I understand of course that my update triggers could be called in any order (see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46257863/2518722). So for example, I could receive the trigger for the update to 3 before the ones for 1 and 2. I also understand that the trigger may be called twice (see: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#execution_guarantees).

**But**: can I guarantee that the `before.data()` passed to my function in the will accurately reflect the 'before' state of the document?

That is, can I expect to see all of the following a triggers at least once?

1. Trigger with `before.data().unreadMessages` = 0 and `after.data().unreadMessages` = 1.
2. Trigger with `before.data().unreadMessages` = 1 and `after.data().unreadMessages` = 2.
3. Trigger with `before.data().unreadMessages` = 2 and `after.data().unreadMessages` = 3.

Can I guarantee that I won't receive for example a trigger where `before.data().unreadMessages` = 0 and `after.data().unreadMessages` = 3?

I presume that since `FieldValue.increment` is performed atomically that this is a safe assumption, but I need to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have that guarantee.  The data would be nearly useless otherwise.