# The time an event occurred in background cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

According to the documentation there are no guarantees in which order events in background cloud functions will be executed. However the object `EventContext` has a property `timestamp` which seems should guaranteed to represent at least the order in which events occurred in the past.

Can we use value from this property to insure that old events are not getting processed?  (for example we will have a transaction block inside cloud function and read another document in it for latest processed event timestamp)

Comment: Have you checked [How to deal with firebase trigger function execution order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46257544/how-to-deal-with-firebase-trigger-function-execution-order)?  Also can you give more context on what you are trying to do? Are these functions scheduled or some Firestore triggers and what they do? Then someone might be able to provide a workaround.

Comment: Did you have a chance to look at the thread mentioned by @Dharmaraj? Does it answer your question? If not, please share more context of your requirement

Comment: After reading the thread one thing is still not clear to me:`EventContext.timestamp` is a time when event is delivered to cloud function or a time when event happens (such as document update)?

Comment: EventContext.timestamp is the time when the even happened. You can check more info in the following [document.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions_.eventcontext)